# Domain and Range of Piecewise Function Help

Tags: calculus

I have a graph of a piecewise function below, and I am having trouble figuring out the domain of the function in interval notation.

[image]

My answers are:

Domain: $[-7, -1)\cup(-1, \infty)$

Range: $[-6, \infty)$

I am told my range is correct but my domain is wrong, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: What is $f(10)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's look at your graph, and where the discontinuities lie. The first is at $x=-5$, a removable discontinuity, the second at $x=-1$, an asymptotic discontinuity, and the third at $x=3$, a jump discontinuity.

Now we notice that the function simply isn't defined at $x=-5$, so that can't be part of the domain. The same can be said for $x=-1$, but the function **is** defined for $x=3$, so it's part of the domain.

Hence, our answer is $$[-7,\infty)\setminus\{-5,-1\}$$or$$[-7,-5)\cup(-5,-1)\cup(-1,\infty)$$

Comment: What is $f(9)$ ?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Given the function was not cut off, I made the presumption that the function went off the infinity linearly. Of course, that's not guaranteed to be true, but from personal experience with these sorts of problems, both answers tend to be accepted as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's due to the difference between a blue dot and a white dot. I guess the white dot means that the function is not defined there. Hence the domain would exclude $-5$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is

$$[-7,-5)\cup (-5,-1)\cup (-1,8]$$

the range is
$$[-6,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

When you see the white dot, it just means that the function is not defined at that point. So, $f(-5)$ is undefined, also $f(-1)$ is undefined, but $f(3) = 0$.

Also, the domain does not stop at $x = 8$; it goes all the way to $\infty$. Some textbooks add an arrow to show it goes to $\infty$.   Finally, your domain is:  $$[−7,−5)∪(−5,−1)∪(−1,\infty).$$

Comment: Maybe better to say "when you see the white dot with no blue dot above or below"